# How to do a callback between two projects?

Tags: java, callback, osgi

I am working in two java projects. The first supports OSGi components, second does not. The first depend to the second for logging.

My need is to add a callback in the second project from the first to recover a variable to add in the log.

Comment: Add it as a project/files library via your IDE

Comment: I think a bit more explanation is needed. In general, if A depends on B but B must "callback", then B should define a callback interface of which A provides an instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As John B said, I defined an interface in the second project which is implemented in the first project. This one, must give an instance of the class which implements the interface to the second project.